# How do I specify an input buffer to lex and yacc?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I have to create an Assembler, with lex and yacc but I have to give the input to lex from a c file, where I have my main function. But how do I do such thing?

I just have a buffer.

```
char *buffer;
```

But I want to know how I could pass that buffer to lex.

I just expect to give a buffer to lex from a "C" file.
I want an example showing how to do so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning from a buffer is pretty easy, but it's almost certainly *not* what you want to do.

If you want to scan from a file, you simply open the file for reading, saving the value from the `fopen` call into `yyin`. Make sure that you check that the `fopen` succeeded, because if `yyin` ends up being NULL (which is what will happen if the `fopen` fails) then the scanner will read from `stdin`.

You'll need to declare `yyin`, unless the part of your program which sets up in the input file is contained in the same translation unit as your scanner definition. The declaration is:

```
extern FILE* yyin;
```

If you really want to read from a single string in memory, you just call

```
yy_scan_string(buffer);
```

before you start scanning. (There is also a function which takes both a buffer address and a length, which you can use for inputs which are not NUL-terminated and possibly include NUL bytes:

```
yy_scan_bytes(buffer, buflen);
```

But the buffer you provide must be the entire input; you don't use this interface to read a file a line at a time. (There are ways to do that, but I really don't think that's what you're looking for. It's described in the [Multiple Input Buffers section of the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) if you're curious.)

Comment: Thank you so much now it worked, but after it finishes parsing, it gives me a Segmentantion Fault error. Also when I remove the yyparse function it runs ok but it doesn't parse anything.

Comment: @Camin: Since the `yyparse` function is what does the parse, it is not surprising that if you don't call it, your program does not parse anything. I have no idea why your program segfaults at the end, but I think that would be a new question. Please recall that if you ask for debugging assistance, we require a precise problem description including a [mcve] which shows us exactly what you are doing.